# I have a program that writes to a log file and I want to view the log file from within the program

Tags: c#, logging

> The error is System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\WpfApp1911097\bin\Debug\TextWriterOutput.log' because it is being used by another process.'

I write to the log file using:

```
///Write to external file
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("various data ");
/// You must close or flush the trace to empty the output buffer.
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Flush();
```

The program to view the log file when a button is clicked is as follows:

```
private void DisplayExternal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
            DisplayText.Text = filetext;
        }   
    }
}
```

Obviously I get the error when I select the log file so I need to disconnect the log file somehow after wrting to it.

Comment: Try this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389155/easiest-way-to-read-text-file-which-is-locked-by-another-application

Comment: You're not showing us how you write to the file.

Comment: Yes - the two lines of code work, but  had to add code to the App.Config   <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>

Comment: Thanks Tom - works like a dream and so simple!